# Set state with radio buttons, React, to render conditionally

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to set a state to do some conditional rendering, but I can't get it to work. The idea is simple, change input with radio buttons and you'll see a different element.

```
import { useState } from "react";

function Form() {
  const [state, setState] = useState();

  function setValue(changeEvent) {
    setState({ state: changeEvent.target.value });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" value={true} name="option" onChange={setValue} />
        <span>Oui</span>
        <input type="radio" value={false} name="option" onChange={setValue} /> <span>Non</span>
      </div>

      {state ? <div>You said yes! </div> : <div>You said no! </div>}
    </>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

When I log the state, the values are correct, but the rendering is only changing once in the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way of doing it.

```
import { useState } from "react";

function Form() {
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState(false);
  const toggleAnswer = () => setAnswer(!answer);


  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" value={true} name="option" onClick={toggleAnswer} />
        <span>Oui</span>
        <input type="radio" value={false} name="option" onClick={toggleAnswer} /> <span>Non</span>
      </div>
      {answer ? <div>You said yes! </div> : <div>You said no! </div>}

    </>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  function setValue(changeEvent) {
    setState(changeEvent.target.value);
  }
```

With useState hook you don't need to pass whole component state object, just single state value

Comment: No luck, I am quite sure the state is changing, and that the problem is the rendering.

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer I tried that, but no I get 2 errors: 

Warning: Received the string `false` for the boolean attribute `checked`. The browser will interpret it as a truthy value. Did you mean checked={false}?

Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

That second one I have seen multiple times while trying stuff to fix this, but I do not get what it means..

Comment: try to set default value: `const [state, setState] = useState(false);`

Comment: I am not sure but maybe value should be a string, not a boolean, like `value="true"` and then `checked={state === "true"}`

Comment: Na... The state is correct, but somehow is doesn't render correctly.. Thanks for trying anyways!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very simple, when you use `setState` you are passing an object that has a property named `state` that has a value (true or false).

so when you are asking for the `state` it will always be `true` because you have an object that is not falsy.

in order to see what you are storing add this before your divs...

```js
{JSON.stringify(state, null, 2)}
```

you will then see

```json
{"state": false}
```

or

```json
{"state": true}
```

depending on your choice... so the answer was given by Oskar. But just to be clear, you are doing `state = {"state": false}` so maybe read some more at [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)